# I create some document to mongoose but not showing

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I tried to create 5 documents in mondoDB , and I’m sure that I successfully created 5 documents.

But it only shows one document on Robo3T.

Here is my code

```
const Category = require('../category')

const db = require('../../config/mongoose')
const categoryList = require('./categoryList.json')

db.once('open', () => {

  return Promise.all(Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, index) => {
      Category.create({ 
        name: categoryList[index].name,
        icon: categoryList[index].icon
      })
  }))

    .then(() => console.log('categorySeeder.js is done'))
    .then(() => process.exit())
})
```

And here is my Robo3T
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtgAw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use aysnc/await

```
await Promise.all(Array.from({ length: 5}).map(async (_, index) => {
      let categoryObj = new Category({ name: categoryList[index].name, icon: categoryList[index].icon });
      categoryObj.save().then(res => console.log(`Created book ${res}`));
}));
```

Comment: I tried this but it pop out 

`SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

btw, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
const Category = require('../category')

const db = require('../../config/mongoose')
const categoryList = require('./categoryList.json')

db.once('open', async () => {

  return Promise.all(Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_, index) => {
      return new Category({ 
        name: categoryList[index].name,
        icon: categoryList[index].icon
      }).save();
      
     // or
      return Category.create({ 
        name: categoryList[index].name,
        icon: categoryList[index].icon
      });
  }))

    .then(() => console.log('categorySeeder.js is done'))
    .then(() => process.exit())
})
```

Try this

Comment: `return Category.create`

I tried this and it was work, thank you very much!!!

Could you tell me why it's work??
I tried my best but can't figure out.